# Create Ruby hash without `to_h` method

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a key/value pair for all letters of the English alphabet.

In Ruby 2.1 I can use:

```
('a'..'z').each_with_index.to_h
# => { "a" => 0, "b" => 1, "c" => 2, ... }
```

However, in Ruby 1.9.x, the `to_h` method doesn't exist.  What is the best solution for this case?

Comment: Point of clarification: `Enumerable#to_h` wasn't added until 2.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Hash constructor/factory method ::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), passing it key/value pairs as two element arrays.

```
Hash[ ('a'..'z').each_with_index.to_a ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Hash[('a'..'z').zip(0..25)]
```

You can zip them together too

Comment: You can even omit the extra pair of parentheses: `.zip(0..25)`

Comment: Because `Range` is `Enumerable` and `Enumerable#zip` exist. No need `#to_a`.

Comment: I accepted Neil Slater's answer for being first, but I like this answer for brevity :) thanks!

Comment: A nice thing about this approach - you can use it to map any `Range` to any other `Range` of the same size. The other answers construct a second array from the first - which I think is simpler design, but less flexible than this answer could prove when that is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use splat operator(`*`) too :

```
Hash[ *('a'..'z').each_with_index ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use splat operator:

```
=> Hash[[*[*'a'..'z'].map.with_index]]
=# {"a"=>0, "b"=>1, "c"=>2, "d"=>3, "e"=>4, "f"=>5, "g"=>6, "h"=>7......}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant:

```
Hash[(0..25).map { |i| [(97+i).chr, i] }]
```